# Elasticseach or query for comma separated values

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I am saving id's in the database as comma separated and indexing the same to ElasticSearch. Now I need to retrieve if the user_id matches with the value.

For example it it saving like this in the indexing for the column user_ids (database type is varchar(500) in elasticsearch it is text)

8938,8936,8937

```
$userId = 8936; // For example expecting to return that row
$whereCondition = [];
$whereCondition[]  = [
                "query_string" => [
                    "query"=> $userId,
                    "default_field" => "user_ids",
                    "default_operator" => "OR"
                ]
            ];

$searchParams = [
    'query' => [
        'bool' => [
            'must' => [
                $whereCondition
            ],
            'must_not' => [
                ['exists' => ['field' => 'deleted_at']]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "size" => 10000
];

User::search($searchParams);
```

Json Query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                [{
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": 8936,
                        "default_field": "user_ids",
                        "default_operator": "OR"
                    }
                }]
            ],
            "must_not": [
                [{
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "deleted_at"
                    }
                }]
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 10000
}
```

Mapping details

```
{
    "user_details_index": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "test_type": {
                "properties": {
                    "created_at": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                    },
                    "deleted_at": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                    },
                    "updated_at": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                    },
                    "user_ids": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "creation_date": "1546404165500",
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "krpph26NTv2ykt6xE05klQ",
                "version": {
                    "created": "6020299"
                },
                "provided_name": "user_details_index"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying with above logic, but not unable to retrieve. Can someone help on this.

Comment: Please share the mapping of index. Also please share the query in json format that is accepted by _search api of elasticsearch. This would make easy for people here to understand the query.

Comment: @NishantSaini updated the question

Comment: Please add index mapping as well. To get mapping use `GET <indexname>/_mappings`

Comment: @NishantSaini no mapping properties for that column default settings has been applied

Comment: why went with the comma-separated values, have you considered nested fields before doing so?

Comment: @NishantSaini updated question for clarification purposes

Comment: Even if the field is auto-created by elastic it will appear in mapping. I guess you are targeting wrong index.

Comment: @SunderR no we have not considered fields, is there any way to achieve what I need with current or do I need to change. If change request what kind of change

Comment: @NishantSaini updated question as per checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the field `user_ids` is of type `text` any no analyzer is specified for it by default it will use `standard` analyzer which won't break `8938,8936,8937` into terms `8938`, `8936` and `8937` and hence the id can't match.

To solve this I would suggest you to store array of ids to `user_ids` field instead of csv. So while indexing you json input should look as below:

```
{
   ...

   "user_ids": [
      8938,
      8936,
      8937
   ]

   ...
}
```

Since user ids are integer values following changes should be done in mapping:

```
{
   "user_ids": {
      "type": "integer"
   }
}
```

The query will be now as follow:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        [
          {
            "terms": {
              "userIds": [
                8936
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      ],
      "must_not": [
        [
          {
            "exists": {
              "field": "deleted_at"
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 10000
}
```

Comment: Getting number format exception while trying to do like that type "number_format_exception"
reason "For input string: \"[8936]\""

Comment: sometimes records it has only one value and other times it has more than one

Comment: It should not be passed as string, instead it should be array.

Comment: Thanks I will check MySQL how to prepare array in the select(as I am indexing records from MySQL rows directly) that will solve this issue hopefully

Comment: Since you are using PHP ; once you get ids in csv from DB, use `$userIdsArray = explode(',',  $useridsCsv)`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help